# How to determine if user selected a file for file upload in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, upload

Suppose, I have an input

```
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" />
```

In the real time, I need to output an alert if a file was selected for this input. If a file wasn't selected and user simply dismissed files manager window I don't need to output an alert.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `change` event to do this. Under that event you can check the `value` of the file input. If it's empty, no file was chosen.

```
$('#uploadFile').change(function() {
    if (this.value) {
        alert('you chose a file!');
    }
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xm0qj8n0/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "file");
x.setAttribute("id", "uploadFile");
x.onchange = function() {
    alert("File Selected");
}
document.body.appendChild(x);
/*
if(x.value == "") {
    alert("File is not Selected");
}
*/
```

This example may help you. W3Schools is best for JS.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_files

Comment: `W3Schools is best for JS.` I'm afraid it's really not. Their references are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) instead